# Facebook Graph API Explorer does not give me location

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Using facebook graph API explorer with "me?fields=location" and found that location information is not displayed with "Field is empty or disallowed..." message, even with user_location scope added. Why?

Comment: works fine for me. which is all i can tell you, we need a lot more details from you. api version, exact result message, did you definitely select a location in your facebook settings, ...

Comment: v3.2 , result : {"id": "xxxx"}, location service on, and tried check in, but still no result

Comment: Got it! it is not live location nor checkin, it is the location we set manually at profile..

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a location in your Facebook settings. It´s not a live location - that would be possible without Facebook: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API